# Datasets that input GPS and output historical time-series

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical, time-series, environment

I'm wondering what kind of historical time-series data I can get given GPS coordinates as input.

More than anything I'm interested in:

- Temperature
- Precipitation
- Humidity
- Irradiation

I'm largely interested in environmental data, but anything that could be identified by the cross section of a date and a gps coordinate would be of interest. Also, I'd prefer if it included data on the European continent.

Does anyone have any suggestions for where I may acquire such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **Daily Global Weather Measurements, 1929-2009 (NCDC, GSOD)** dataset contains:

> A collection of daily weather measurements (temperature, wind speed, humidity, pressure, &c.) from 9000+ weather stations around the world.
>
> Global summary of day data for 18 surface meteorological elements are derived from the synoptic/hourly observations contained in USAF DATSAV3 Surface data and Federal Climate Complex Integrated Surface Data (ISD). Historical data are generally available for 1929 to the present, with data from 1973 to the present being the most complete.

The data is global, including ocean measurements, will contain frequent daily measurements as well as latitude and longitude coordinates.

---

One common way to get this [dataset](https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/2759) is through the hosting by Amazon Web Services, and the original details are found at the [NOAA](http://www.climate.gov/daily-observational-data-global-summary-day-gsod-%E2%80%93-gis-data-locator) site.

[image]

Caveat: the license says

> This data set can only be used within the United States.

So perhaps your 1 year of [free tier AWS instance](http://aws.amazon.com/free) can be set up in the US.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. The license is sort of a problem, but as this is academic, I'll see what I can do to get around it. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.