# 1945 (spring) daily weather Germany

Tags: data-request, weather, historical, germany

Perhaps understandably, I am having difficulty tracking down daily weather data for Germany in early 1945.

My specific interest is in daily temps and any other daily weather observations for January through March 1945, particularly for the area of Bonn or Cologne -- although I would be grateful even if such data were only available for Berlin.  My greatest interest is in the first three weeks of March 1945.

Comment: [This answer](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4729/1511) has some weather station data from 1929, but you'd have to check if Germany goes back that far.

Comment: To see how weather was presented in 1945, [here are UK examples](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/archive/9529)

Comment: The German DWD office may have what you want, but I can't read German well enough to know. Here's another stackoverflow related questions with answers - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/365/downloadable-archive-of-weather-conditions-for-europe

Comment: http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-lite/1945/ might have this data, but you'll have to check the Master Location Identifier Database (MLID) on http://www.weathergraphics.com/identifiers/ to be sure

Comment: U might read “A woman in Berlin”. Supposedly an autobiographical diary during the Soviet invasion

Answer (score 4):

For German daily data, start here at the Deutschewettersdienst website.

<s>ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/daily/kl/historical/</s>

ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/observations_germany/climate/daily/kl/historical/

Open the file KL_Tageswerte_Beschreibung_Stationen.txt to find a station with data for the location and time period that you want.  For Bonn, it looks like station ID 599 "Bonn-Friesdorf" covers 1932 through 1999;  for Cologne, station ID 2665 Koln-Botanischer Garten covers 1936 thru 1984.

Then, find the zipfile for that station, e.g. tageswerte_00599_19321001_19990301_hist.zip
or tageswerte_02665_19360101_19841231_hist.zip

Within the zipfile will be a large textfile named something like produkt_klima_Tageswerte_19321001_19990301_00599.txt which contains daily records of temperature (avg, high, low, air pressure, precipitation, etc.)  It's raw data, so you'll have to find the column headings at the top, then read down the rows until you find the date that you want.

The only problem is that, for fairly obvious reasons, the stations stop recording and have data gaps beginning in 1944 or 1945, resuming again in late 1945 and 1946.  However, I have found two Berlin stations - 417 Berlin-Lichterfelde(Sud) and 402 Berlin-Dahlem (LFAG) - that continue recording up to March 31, 1945 and April 24, 1945, respectively.

Makes you think.

Answer (score 1):

The publicly available [Daily Global Weather Measurements (1929-2009)](https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/daily-global-weather-measurements-1929-2009-ncdc-gsod/) may include measurements in Germany for that period. The dataset is 20GB in total and well structured.

> Global summary of day data for 18 surface meteorological elements are derived from the synoptic/hourly observations contained in USAF DATSAV3 Surface data and Federal Climate Complex Integrated Surface Data (ISD). Historical data are generally available for 1929 to the present, with data from 1973 to the present being the most complete. For some periods, one or more countries' data may not be available due to data restrictions or communications problems. In deriving the summary of day data, a minimum of 4 observations for the day must be present (allows for stations which report 4 synoptic observations/day). Since the data are converted to constant units (e.g, knots), slight rounding error from the originally reported values may occur (e.g, 9.9 instead of 10.0).

If you dig around with a search engine, you'll find alternative downloads or ports. For example, from the NCDC ([link](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets)).

(The license requires that the data is only used in the US.)

Comment: Broken link, https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/gsod/ seems to work better.