# Historical weather data for Pyrenees Atlantiques

Tags: data-request, weather, france

I really need to get hold of historical weather (precipitation, temperature most important) of an area in the Pyrenees Atlantiques. More specifically at a refuge, Arlet Lat/Lon: 42.83570°N / 0.6125°W, but I realise I won't get data that accurate. Any help would be massively appreciated. This is urgently needed for a project we're currently working on, investigating amphibian declines in the area.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean historical? A few hours, a few days, a few months, a few years? Do you need the data specifically in Arlet or Tarbes would be ok?

Comment: Please see this answer http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6412/1511

Comment: I assume you are familiar with ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ and that it does not meet your needs?

Answer (score 4):

[Here you'll find historical weather data near Tarbes](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/donnees-synop-essentielles-omm@public/?tab=table&geofilter.polygon=%2843.41382673441976,-0.49713134765625%29,%2843.10178502605182,1.2387084960937498%29,%2842.683243010466484,1.07940673828125%29,%2842.71755734268774,-0.3680419921875%29,%2843.41382673441976,-0.49713134765625%29&location=8,42.75105,0.7608&basemap=mapbox.streets) between 2010 and 2015. It would probably be a good first approximation of Arlet's data.

Météo France won't open any more geographically precise historical weather data for now.

Though you may have two other solutions:
- Other countries have released as Open Data their historical model data worldwide (as the US). You may have a bit of work to use them since the data are in the Grib format and there are pretty big.
- At OpenDataSoft we've got a private Beta of a weather JSON API that includes AROME and ARPEGE models forecast (every ~2km in France), if you only need weeks/months historical data you can create a dataset from it. Please let me know if you're interested!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can contact Meteofrance. They will for sure find the data you want but it may neither be free nor open.

Else you can try to contact CACG at Tarbes. They may have partial data on it.

Departemental archive sometimes contain weather reports and universities can also contain temperature charts, but you'll have to enter the data yourself