# Historic weather data for Germany in 1938

Tags: weather, germany

I am writing a book about my father, who was a Holocaust survivor. Does anyone know how I can find out what the weather was like in Bavaria, Germany (specifically, Weiden), on November 9-10, 1938 — kristallnacht?

Comment: Actually, this is a possible duplicate of [1945 (spring) daily weather Germany](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6313/1511)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1945 (spring) daily weather Germany](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4885/1945-spring-daily-weather-germany)

Answer (score 3):

@Philsheim points out the very useful weather data discussed in [1945 (spring) daily weather Germany](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6313/1511)

Sadly, it looks like data for Weiden in that set only goes back to 1947, as do most nearby weather records. The closest seems to be Gößweinstein (site 1689); it's at 49.8N, 11.3E compared to Weiden's 49.7N, 12.18E. So same latitude, but almost a full degree west - at a guess, it's about fifty miles away? A little further east is Nürnberg-Buchenbuehl (site 3666). It's quite possible the weather will be different from that at Weiden, but it's worth having a look.