# Berlin weather in 1929

Tags: weather

I am writing a novel set in Berlin in 1929. Does anyone know where I can find out what the weather was in Berlin in that year, especially May? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow this is a duplicate! https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4885/1511